# AWS: ERROR: Pre-processing of application version xxx has failed and Some application versions failed to process. Unable to continue deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloud9

Hi I am trying to deploy a node application from cloud 9 to ELB but I keep getting the below error.

> Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
> --- Waiting for Application Versions to be pre-processed --- ERROR: Pre-processing of application version app-491a-200623_151654 has
> failed. ERROR: Some application versions failed to process. Unable to
> continue deployment.

I have attached an image of the IAM roles that I have. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your console and open up your elastic beanstalk console. Go to both applications and environments and delete them. Then in your terminal hit

```
eb init #Follow instructions

eb create --single ##Follow instructions.
```

It would fix the error, which is due to some application states which are failed. If you want to check those do

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this answer as a result of watching a [YouTube tutorial for how to pass the AWS Certified Developer Associate exam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrKRN9zRBWs). If anyone else gets this error as a result of that tutorial, **delete the 002_node_command.config file** created in the tutorial and commit that change, as that is causing the error to occur.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and nothing changed for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are watching AWS Developer Pass Examination Video, and facing issue druing experiment demo. **Try to remove the whole folder of .ebextensions and retry.**
It seems the way of configuration for EB has upgrade by AWS. not like the way in video. Please reach to latest configuration for reference.

Answer (score 0):

A failure within the pre-processing phase, may be caused by an invalid manifest, configuration or .ebextensions file.

If you deploy an (invalid) application version using eb deploy and you enable the preprocess option, The details of the error will not be revealed.

You can remove the --process flag and enable the verbose option to improve error output.

in my case I deploy using this command:

```
eb deploy -l "XXX" -p
```

And can return a failure when I mess around with .ebextensions:

```
ERROR: Pre-processing of application version xxx has failed.
ERROR: Some application versions failed to process. Unable to continue deployment.
```

With that result I can't figure up what is wrong,
but deploying without -p (or --process)and adding -v (verbose) flag:

```
eb deploy -l "$deployname"  -v
```

It returns something more useful:

```
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Creating AppVersion xxx
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - The configuration file .ebextensions/16-my_custom_config_file.config in application version xxx contains invalid YAML or JSON. 
YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 6, column 1:
   (... details of the error ...)
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (#) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

Now I can fix the problem.